# I'm having troubles installing webkit_server on an ubuntu machine

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Niklas B.'s webkit_server and I keep getting this error:

```
xxx@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~/Downloads/webkit-server$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Downloads/webkit-server/src'
g++ -c -include build/webkit_server -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -o build/Version.o Version.cpp
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:59:1: error: one or more PCH files were found, but they were invalid
 #endif
 ^
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:59:1: error: use -Winvalid-pch for more information
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:59:1: fatal error: build/webkit_server: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [build/Version.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Downloads/webkit-server/src'
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'
```

Can anyone help me?

Thx

Comment: What is a "webkit_server"? Apart from that the error message of the compiler seems clear: the source contains invalid stuff which cannot be processed. I suggest you address the party you got that software from. This might also be the effect of incompatible versions of components used during the build process.

Comment: I also get the same error did you fix it ?